# jquery .html() to erase html content

Tags: innerhtml

I have some problem guys.
I have to delete the content of my  with .html() jquery function. All worked fine, but the footer of my iphone phonegap app go to upper. But when I comment or erase the content of my  directly in my html code, all is ok, the footer of my app stay in his place. Please help me.
Here is my code snippets:

```
<script id="div_mainheader" type="text/html">

        <div id="check_place">
            <div id="idcheckin" style="width: 210px; position: relative;" align="left" class="mystatus2 clickable" onclick='showPartnersNearYouPopUp();'>
                <div id="leave" style="top: 81px;"><img src="graphics/picker.png" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: -1px;">

                    CHECK A PLACE ...

                </div>
            </div> 

            <div id="idbtleave" style="position: absolute; top: 81px; left: 270px;">
                <button id="btleave" class="checkout-button" type="button">{{Localize.quit}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </script>
```

And this is the function that I call to erase the content of my  :

```
$('#check_place').html('');
```

I've also tried `document.getElementById('check_place').innerrHTML = '';`  but it's the same thing with .html()

Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$('#check_place').empty();
```

Comment: Thanx John Doe Smith for your answer. 
I've tried $('#check_place').empty(); but the result is the same. :(